# How can I detect white-space and delete delimiter in CSS

Tags: html, css, attributes, jekyll, whitespace

I am trying to add category view in my blog with Jekyll.

#### blog.html

```
<div class="blog-category">
    {% assign categories_list = site.categories %}
        {% for category in categories_list %}
            <small>
                <a class="category" href="{{site.baseurl}}/categories/{{ category[0] | downcase }}.html">{{ category[0] | capitalize }}</a>
            </small>
        {% endfor %}
    {% assign categories_list = nil %}
</div>
```

#### CSSfile.scss

```
.blog-category {
    width: 80% !important;
    margin: auto;
    white-space: normal;
    text-align: center !important;
    word-spacing: 1.5em;

    small::before {
        content: " | ";
    }

    small:first-child::before {
        content: "";
    }
}
```

#### You will see like this.

**If screen is wide**

classA | classB | classC | classD | classE | classF | 
classG | classH | classI | classJ | classK

**If screen is narrow**

classA | classB | classC | 
classD | classE | classF | 
classG | classH | classI | 
classJ | classK

#### My Problem Explaination

As you can see, there is delimiter next to "classF"(classC, classI also) because I put delimiter " | " by coding `content: " | ";` in css file. **What I want to do is deleting delimiter when there is white-space(Actually, line-break).**

Please, help me to fix my problem :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't figure out any way to solve this with pure CSS.

I tried in this way:

```
$(window).on("resize", (function() {
    var isLast = false;
    $("a").removeClass("Last")
    $("a").each(function() {   
        if (isLast && isLast.offset().top != $(this).offset().top) {
            isLast.addClass("Last");
        } 
        isLast = $(this);
    }).last().addClass("Last");
})).resize();
```

The idea is to iterate each  element to check if the previous one is on the same line, if not, the previous one is the last of the line; in this case a new class "Last" is added.
The class "Last" is set as:

```
.Last:after {
  content: "";
}
```

where the `<a>` element is:

```
small a:after {
        content: " | ";
    }
```

Furthermore I binded to the resize event to the window object then `.resize()` to call it immediatly onload.
Those last actions are important, of course, for responsive purpose on changing the window's size.

I simplified little bit your code, just to speed up, but you'd be anyway able to figure out how to adapt to yours...

http://jsfiddle.net/9z2ug5oj/1/

finally, i'd display the `<a>` elements as `inline-block`, just to avoid the single element splitting on two lines:

```
small a {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9z2ug5oj/2/

Comment: Thanks. But, I really want to get rid of all Javascripts in my blog.. :( I hope there is the only way to solve this without it.

Comment: And also, I think using ```offset().top``` is a little bit dangerous choice because I already got some bugs in your jsfiddle.net that you put on your answer :(

Answer (score 0):

This script detects the first child after a line-break and adds a class 'first' to it.

This is the SCSS:

```
.blog-category {
    width: 80% !important;
    margin: auto;
    white-space: normal;
    text-align: center !important;
    word-spacing: 1.5em;

    small {white-space: nowrap; display: inline-block;}
    small a {text-decoration: none;}
    small a::before {
        content: "| ";
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    small:first-child a::before, small.first a::before {
        color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    }
}
```

And this is the jQuery:

```
$(window).on("resize", (function() {
  $('.blog-category small').removeClass('first');
  var top;
  $('.blog-category').children().each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        _top = $this.position().top;

    if (top === undefined) {
        top = _top;
    } else if (top < _top) {
        top = _top;
        $this.addClass('first');
    }
  });
}));
```

With a working demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xPZeOE

Comment: Thank you for the help. But the problem is I am afraid that there is bug. Please go to your demo link and make your browser windows wide to 760px, 655px etc. You can see there is delimiter at the last part. Of course, it works at the first time but, I think there is some sort of bug in ```offset().top```.

Comment: I do not see the bug (in Firefox). What do you mean?

Comment: Ah, found it! Chrome CSS defaults... I have updated the demo.

Answer (score 0):

There is a CSS-only solution, but that only works with a left-aligned 'list', not with a center-aligned one. I know that this is not exactly what the OP asked, but I did not want to keep this from you all. It is so simple... it is beautiful ;-).

This HTML:

```
<div class="holder">
  <div class="inner">
    |&nbsp;classA
    |&nbsp;classB
    |&nbsp;classC
    |&nbsp;classD
    |&nbsp;classE
    |&nbsp;classF
    |&nbsp;classG
    |&nbsp;classH
    |&nbsp;classI
    |&nbsp;classJ
    |&nbsp;classK
  </div>
</div>
```

... along with this CSS:

```
.holder {overflow: hidden;}
.inner {position: relative; left: -5px;}
```

See a [working example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GOgLge).

Comment: Well, I am sorry to say that I didn't want like this.(If this sentence seems rude, Sorry for its expression. English is not my 1st language..)
The problem is I don't know how many childs(categories) are there. Because it is generated by Liquid syntax. Btw, Thank you for giving me a help.

Comment: I assume you do not want it because it is left-aligned. The amount of categories does not matter here.